# Select box change event not appear inside modal bootstrap when reopen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

i created select box change event when option in select box is "reschedule" inside bootstrap modal.

first time pop up modal change event is working. but when modal is closed and reopened change event is not running when select "reschedule" in select box.

how to solve this problem

this is script for change event select box

```js
const date = document.getElementById('date');
$('#selector').on('change', function() {
  var divClass = $(this).val();
  $(".op").hide();
  $("." + divClass).slideDown('medium');
  const value = document.getElementById('selector').value;
  date.required = (value == "Reschedule");
});
```

```css
.op {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-left:4px;">

  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="form-group row">

      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="user_uid">Action</label>

      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name="agree" class="form-control" id="selector" required>

          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Action..</option>

          <option value="Accepted">Accept</option>

          <option value="Reschedule">Reschedule</option>

          <option value="Rejected">Reject</option>

        </select>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="row op Reschedule" style="margin-left:4px;">

  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="form-group row">

      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label " for="user_uid">Reschedule Datetime</label>

      <div class="col-sm-10">



        <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" type="datetime-local" min="<?php echo date(" Y-m-d "); ?>T00:00">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>



</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

i use another file to save the contents of the modal and open using javascript to send variabel using GET.

this is script for modal javascript

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewdata" data-id="' . $row['id_cdd'] . '" class="viewda dropdown-item" aria-label="Left Align" style="cursor:pointer" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" title="View"> View </a>

 <div id="viewdata" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Candidate Detail</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="idview" name="idview"></input>
                <div class="modal-body body-view">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
        $(document).on("click", ".viewda", function() {
            var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
            var myBook2 = $(this).data('session');
            $(".body-view #idview").val(myBookId);
            $.ajax({
                url: "cdd_inc_modal.php?view=" + myBookId+"&session="+myBook2,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    $(".body-view").html("");
                    $(".body-view").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#selector').on('change', function() {` wont watch for any dom changes, this will only work on the initial modal render... you need to watch the entire doc for newly appended elements, just like your second snippet. Try this... `$(document).on('change', '#selector', function() {`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. my problem solve with simple way